# Searching JSON PHP

Tags: php, json, search

I have JSON that looks like this (shortened for readability):

```
{
    "heroes": [
         {
            "name": "antimage",
            "id": 1,
            "localized_name": "Anti-Mage"
        },
        {
            "name": "axe",
            "id": 2,
            "localized_name": "Axe"
        },
        {
            "name": "bane",
            "id": 3,
            "localized_name": "Bane"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a PHP variable that is equal to one of the three ids. I need to search the JSON for the `id` and return the localized name. This is what I’m trying so far.

```
$heroid = $myplayer['hero_id'];

$heroes = file_get_contents("data/heroes.json");
$heroesarray = json_decode($heroes, true);

foreach ($heroesarray as $parsed_key => $parsed_value) {
        if ($parsed_value['id'] == $heroid) {
    $heroname = $parsed_value['localized_name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop and loop through the decoded array. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use the json_decode function to convert the JSON into an PHP array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Just use [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Explanation follows the code at the bottom.

```
// First set the ID you want to look for.
$the_id_you_want = 2;

// Next set the $json.
$json = <<<EOT
{
    "heroes": [
         {
            "name": "antimage",
            "id": 1,
            "localized_name": "Anti-Mage"
        },
        {
            "name": "axe",
            "id": 2,
            "localized_name": "Axe"
        },
        {
            "name": "bane",
            "id": 3,
            "localized_name": "Bane"
        }
    ]
}
EOT;

// Now decode the json & return it as an array with the `true` parameter.
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

// Set to 'TRUE' for testing & seeing what is actually being decoded.
if (FALSE) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($decoded);
  echo '</pre>';
}

// Now roll through the decoded json via a foreach loop.
foreach ($decoded as $decoded_array_key => $decoded_array_value) {
  // Since this json is an array in another array, we need anothe foreach loop.
  foreach ($decoded_array_value as $decoded_key => $decoded_value) {
    // Do a comparison between the `$decoded_value['id']` and $the_id_you_want
    if ($decoded_value['id'] == $the_id_you_want) {
      echo $decoded_value['localized_name'];
    }
  }
}
```

Okay, the reason my first try at this did not work—and neither did yours—is your JSON structure was nested one more level deep that what is expected. See the debugging code I have in place with `print_r($decoded);`? This is the output when decoded as an array:

```
Array
(
    [heroes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => antimage
                    [id] => 1
                    [localized_name] => Anti-Mage
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => axe
                    [id] => 2
                    [localized_name] => Axe
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => bane
                    [id] => 3
                    [localized_name] => Bane
                )

        )

)
```

First you have an array to begin with which could equate to `$decoded[0]` and then below that you have another array that equates to `$decoded[0]['heroes']` and then in there is the array that contains the values which is structured as `$decoded[0]['heroes'][0]`, `$decoded[0]['heroes'][1]`, `$decoded[0]['heroes'][2]`.

But the key to solving this was the `print_r($decoded);` which helped me see the larger structure of your JSON.

Comment: It's not working for me I'll edit post above with what I'm trying.

Answer (score 1):

[`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) takes a JSON string and (if the second parameter is `true`) turns it into an associate array.  We then loop through this data with a [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) until we find the hero you want.

```
$json = ''; // JSON string
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($data['heroes'] as $hero) {
    if($hero['id'] === 2) {
        var_dump($hero['localized_name']);
        // Axe

        // This will stop the loop, if you want to keep going remove this line
        break;
    }
}
```